# How do I search for new files in a Box.com Folder in SSIS to detect a new file and process the data in this file?

Tags: ssis, etl, box, file-watcher

I've developed a SSIS ETL job/workflow to scan for new files in a folder and load the data from the new file into a SQL Server table. This job basically implements searches for a file with a predefined file name pattern in a predefined folder location. I followed all the steps mentioned [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/91665/). However, the tricky part is that my company uses Box.com for file storage and the particular folder where the SSIS job has to search for new files is on Box.com. When I use my local Box-Sync Path and run the job on my local machine, I am able to execute the entire package successfully and load the new data into the required table. However, when I deploy this job in the SSIS Catalog and try to run it from the Server, the job fails as the SQL Server is unable to resolve the local Box-Sync Path that's specific to my machine.

Could anyone suggest which path I should be using to get rid of this error and schedule the job successfully on the Server.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a Box-Sync path on a server that your SSIS agent has access to and use either a UNC path to that Sync folder, or a path that is local to your SSIS Server.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answers. I am pretty new to using Box Storage and sorry if my question seems too vague. I am not sure of what you meant by creating a Box Sync Path on a server that my SSIS Agent has access to. Would it be possible to create a Box Sync Path on, for instance, say a SQL Server?

I tried mapping the Box Sync to a Network Drive and using UNC Path to the Sync Folder. The ETL package is not throwing any errors, however it is also unable to find the new file placed in the specified folder. There's nothing in the Execution Results that I can use. Please help! TIA

Comment: This is starting to sound like it should be a question for Box.Com's customer support.  I don't know anything about what you can and can't do with Box.com, but if you followed the same steps as you did when you set up the sync folder on your local box, and set up a sync folder the same way on either your SSIS Server, or a network server, then I can't think of any reason why the SSIS package on your server wouldn't work the same as it does on your local box.

Comment: The solution worked by installing my personal Box Sync Folder on a Windows Share Folder that shares the same VLAN as our SQL Server. However, we still need to look into how files can be synced up on the Windows Share without using my personal Box Sync Folder on the Network Share. Thanks for the help, Tab! :)